# What can cause a block to not retain a referenced Objective-C object under ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I have received a crash report saying this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fb17f90'

This typically happens when an object has been deallocated and another object now lives at the same address as the deallocated object.

Here is my code (the only place in my app where I’m calling the `CGImage` method):

```
@implementation UIImageView (MyApp)

- (void) setImageWithObject:(id)object
{
    NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[object URL]];
    __typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    [self setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CGImageGetHeight(imageRef));
            CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, (size_t)roundf(CGRectGetWidth(rect)), (size_t)roundf(CGRectGetHeight(rect)), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));
            UIImage *decompressedImage = image;
            if (bitmapContext)
            {
                CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, rect, imageRef);
                CGImageRef decompressedImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
                decompressedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:decompressedImageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
                CGImageRelease(decompressedImageRef);
                CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                weakSelf.image = decompressedImage;
            });
        });
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}

@end
```

I assumed that the `image` object should be automatically retained by the block (I’m using ARC) so that the `image` object can’t be deallocated before the code using it is executed on the default priority queue. The crash seems to imply that it was not retained.

Is my assumption wrong or am I missing something else?

Comment: This code is correct. I can only think about two posibilites: 1. the crash is happening somewhere else, not in this code. 2. you have some kind of memory corruption going on in your app.

Comment: Some ideas:  1) put a try/catch around that CGImage call and see if you can catch it?  2) don't release decompressedImageRef until after the weakSelf.image = assignment.

Comment: I've seen a bug with some CGImage routines and bitmap contexts on OS X where it is short a retain and the image data is shared (copy-on-write semantics I think).  This smells like it might be related.

Comment: "This typically happens when an object has been deallocated and another object now lives at the same address as the deallocated object." If you suspect that this is happening, the proper way to test it would be to enable zombies.

Comment: how do you declare your success-block? make sure the block is a copy property if you store it and call it later on.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this similar to the behaviour as with the UIColor and CGColorRef under ARC? As elaborated here: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/296-arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/

So where you have:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
```

I think you need to retain it explicitly within the block and then release it explicitly so ARC does't deallocate the image ref.

So:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageRetain([image CGImage]);
...
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Comment: The problem I described is about `image` being deallocated early, not `imageRef`.

Comment: The "inner pointer problem" has been fixed after iOS 5.1.x:   "NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER
Methods which return pointers (other than Objective C object type) have been decorated with the clang compiler attribute objc_returns_inner_pointer (when compiling with clang) to prevent the compiler from aggressively releasing the receiver expression of those messages, which no longer appear to be referenced, while the returned pointer may still be in use." This also applies to the CGImageRef returned from the property.

Answer (score 0):

There may be no problem in your block itself. Someone calls the block; it would be possible that the caller already passed a deallocated object. I'd do an NSLog (@"%@", image) in the first line of the block and also look at the calling code.